# Java ME: Cannot find class for permission jdk.dio.adc.ADCPermission

Tags: java-me, adc, intel-galileo

I'm trying to set up an analog to digital temperature sensor through Java ME on a Galileo Gen 2. I successfully set up a flame sensor using GPIO pins with the jdk.dio.gpio library in Java ME on my Galileo. However, when I try to access classes in jdk.dio.adc, I get NoClassDefFoundError or when I try to add permissions for ADC, I receive a 'Cannot find class for permissions jdk.dio.adc.ADCPermission'. I can find the proper classes in my JavaME library in my IDE and receive no errors in that regard (however I do receive a InvalidDeviceConfig error, but thats another story).

- Is there a reason these ADC classes are missing from my Galileo?
- How do I fix this?

I know the sensor is connected properly to the Galileo as well because I can read the values directly from the 'in_voltage0_raw' file.

Comment: I have no idea what ADC classes are, but often when classes are missing, it is because you've installed the wrong package. The problem is that JavaME spans over many things. Xlets for office supplies, Xlets for TV settop boxes and Blu-ray discs, MIDlets for phones. And there are different JDK versions of each. You may have installed a wrong one.